# Why is there no rendaku occurring in the word ふかふか?

Tags: onomatopoeia, rendaku, sound-symbolism

Why isn't the second `ふか` changed to `ぶか` in `ふかふか`; thus, becoming `ふかぶか`? I would expect to see `ふかぶか` instead of `ふかふか` for the same reason that `ひとびと` is `ひとびと`, not `ひとひと`. There is no voicing; thus, Lyman's Law cannot be suppressing it.

Comment: Maybe it wouldn't sound fluffy anymore. There's also ふわふわ

Comment: Isn't ふかふか sound symbolism? Most sound symbolism doesn't undergo rendaku.

Comment: Hmm, got any examples of sound symbolisms that DO undergo rendaku?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is impossible to explain exactly when [[連濁]{れんだく}](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendaku) happens and when it doesn't. The linked Wikipedia article also explains:

> In modern Japanese, rendaku is common but at times unpredictable, with
> certain words unaffected by it.

The way I understand it is it happens when two kanji words are combined. For example from the above link:

> [人]{ひと} + [人]{ひと} → [人々]{ひとびと}
>
> hito + hito → hitobito ("person" + "person" → "people")
>
> [時]{とき} + [時]{とき}  → [時時]{ときどき}
>
> toki + toki → tokidoki ("time" + "time" → "sometimes")

However, words such as 'ふかふか' from symbolism ([象徴音]{しょうちょうおん}) don't have corresponding kanjis and [連濁]{れんだく} doesn't occur in such a case.

The link further explains:

> Rendaku thus remains partially unpredictable, sometimes presenting a
> problem even to native speakers, particularly in [Japanese names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_name), where
> rendaku occurs or fails to occur often without obvious cause. In many
> cases, an identically written name may either have or not have
> rendaku, depending on the person. For example, 中田 may be read in a
> number of ways, including both Nakata and Nakada.

Comment: I'd say 音象徴 for _sound symbolism_.

Answer (score 5):

As the other answers point out, *rendaku* doesn't occur in mimetic or onomatopoeic words. The basis is always a particular sound (usually two morae), e.g.

> ふわ

with a particular quality. From this sound the most common mimetic/onomatopoeic words are those obtained by doubling the sound, e.g.

> ふわふわ

but in many cases there is also a common corresponding *to*-adverb, e.g.

> ふわっと

**If *rendaku* were to occur, it would change the quality of the sound.**

In fact, for ふか → ふかふか "fluffy", there is also ぶか → ぶかぶか with a completely different meaning of "too big" or "baggy" [clothes].

Answer (score 3):

`ふかふか` is more like an onomatopoeia (the formation of a word form a sound associated with what is named) instead of connecting two words. 
More examples are:

> - きらきら (shining) [e.g. このダイヤはキラキラしている]
> - はらはら (being nervous) [e.g. ハラハラした]
> - からから (drying)　[e.g. のどがカラカラ]
> - かりかり　(irritating)　[e.g. カリカリしないで]

`ひとびと` is `人々` so it's connecting two words.
if you say `ふかぶか` then it changes the meaning to `深々` (lit: deeply) (e.g. 深々とおじぎする)